# Number of crests and number of waves passing a certain point

Tags: waves, wavelength

Really simple question, I just need to be sure :

> A woman is standing in the sea, and she notices that five wave crests pass in a
>    time of 50 s. Determine the period and frequency of the waves.

Five wave crests passing a point mean that FOUR waves have passed it, thus T = 50/4 = 12.5 and f = 1/12.5 = 0.08 Hz?

Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For the task given, your solution seems correct.